# ASP if statement using databinder

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, data-binding

I have the following code which displays some info inside a table in ASP :

```
<td class="s10"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VTarget")%></td>
<td class="s10"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QTarget")%></td>
```

I want to compare the information from VTarget and QTarget and if the second is greater than the first i want to display a message.

Is there any way to do that using something like an if {...} else {...} statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ternary operator:

```
   <td class="s10"><%# Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QTarget")) > Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VTarget")) ? "Message": "" %></td>
```

Comment: It provides me the follwing error "Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'object'"

Comment: @RaduStanescu try to use Convert.ToInt32 or which ever datatype you are using